# Encoding a file to send to Google AutoML

Tags: go, jpeg, automl

I am writing a golang script to send an image to the prediction engine of Google AutoML API.

It accepts most files using the code below, but certain .jpeg or .jpeg it returns error 500 saying invalid file.  Mostly it works, but I can't figure out the exceptions.  They are perfectly valid jpg's.

I am encoding the payload using EncodeToString.

Among other things, I have tried decoding it, saving it to a PNG, nothing seems to work.  It doesn't like some images.

I wonder if I have an error in my method?  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks

PS the file saves to the filesystem and uploads to S3 just fine.  It's just the encoding to a string when it goes to Google that it fails.

```
imgFile, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

img, fname, err := image.Decode(imgFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fname)
}

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
err = jpeg.Encode(buf, img, nil)

// Encode as base64.
imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes())

defer imgFile.Close()

payload := fmt.Sprintf(`{"payload": {"image": {"imageBytes": "%v"},}}`, imgBase64Str)

// send as a byte
pay := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(payload))
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, URL.String(), pay)
```

Comment: Try to view the image on browser using `"<html><body><img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + imgBase64Str + "\" /></body></html>"` in response.

Comment: Thanks, I just put in a front end with your script and the image renders perfectly, in the same way the S3 upload is fine.  But, still, when posting it in the payload to the API it dies, and I can't see a pattern in the images in which it fails

Comment: May be something wrong when you are creating a payload. Can try to post the image directly.

Comment: I think you are write, it is the payload creation.  It only accepts it in JSON format with base64 images.  I just tried changing the payload quotes but still the same problem:   `payload := fmt.Sprintf("{'payload': {'image': {'imageBytes': '%v'},}}", imgBase64Str)`

Comment: May be there is an extra comma in the payload json `{"payload": {"image": {"imageBytes": "%v"}}}`. Remove comma and then try to post the payload

Comment: I tried that, the extra comma doesn't make sense, but it's in the Docs for automl and the only way it works.... https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/predict#automl-nl-example-cli  --- EDIT, actually it does work with or without the comma, but same issue

Comment: I also tried resizing it in go, then sending the resized image.  That fails.  But, resizing it manually on the command line, then sending the resized version works.  My have to kludge some exec.Command in it as a last resort

Comment: yes the payload json was correct. And the docs shows the way to upload the json in the same format you are using.

Comment: This kludge works `exec.Command("convert", "-resize", "200%", filename, resized).Run()` But, resizing it in GO using https://github.com/nfnt/resize does not.  Shame I have to have it on lambda, so I can't do the exec.... going to keep playing with it, thanks so far

Comment: The general process should also work. May be when you are initializing the buffer it goes wrong. Use `bytes.NewReader([]byte(payload))` to convert the payload to io.reader.

Comment: good idea, but sadly no go. It seems to function with both types of buffer, but the API still only accepts all images if i put it through imagemagick.  Maybe I am going to put it on EC2 for now and just do the resize until they start building the official APIs

Answer (score 1):

I believe I fixed it.

I looked in the Google docs again and for the speech to text (which is a different API) it says to do `encode64 -w 0`

So, looking in Go docs, it seems `RawStdEncoding` is right to use to replicate this behaviour, not `StdEncoding`

No image failures yet.  Hope this helps someone else one day.